# Writing trigger which calculates driving distance?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, update, trigger

Trigger fires but doesn't update my table - COUNTY_VR_GEO_ROUTING.

Here's the output from pgadmin after updating a record -

UPDATE 2
Query returned successfully in 2 secs.

Can anyone give me thoughts on what may be going on?

PostgreSQL 9.6; windows os.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vr_routes.usp_etl_gis_pgr_dist_tigger_fn()
RETURNS TRIGGER 

AS $BODY$
BEGIN
      UPDATE "VOTER_ROUTING".vr_routes."COUNTY_VR_GEO_ROUTING"
      SET dist = agg_cost * 0.000621371 FROM (SELECT agg_cost FROM pgr_dijkstraCost(
           'SELECT gid as id, source, target, length_m AS cost FROM osmways',
            -- source
        (SELECT id FROM osmways_vertices_pgr
            ORDER BY ST_Transform(the_geom,2264) <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(NEW.x1,NEW.y1),2264) LIMIT 1),
        -- target
        (SELECT id FROM osmways_vertices_pgr
            ORDER BY ST_Transform(the_geom,2264) <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(NEW.x2,NEW.y2),2264) LIMIT 1),
        false) 
         ) AS dijkstra; -- undirected

 RETURN NEW;

END; 
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Here's my trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER usp_etl_gis_trigger_county_vr_geo
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON "VOTER_ROUTING".vr_routes."COUNTY_VR_GEO_ROUTING"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE vr_routes.usp_etl_gis_pgr_dist_tigger_fn();
```

Comment: It looks like you have left the letter R out of trigger on your last line and when naming your trigger.